# How do I print the data received on a serial port?

Tags: python, serial-port

[image]Below is the python code I have written :

```
import serial,time
#initialization and open the port
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 1152000
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_TWO #number of stop bits
    #ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 5               #non-block read
    #ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read
ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control

try: 
    ser.open()

except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():
    read_data = ser.read(10)
   # response  = ser.readline()
    print"Data received : " + read_data

else:
   print "Can not open serial port"
```

Upon executing, it shows the data received to be too strange to read. The screen shot of the response has been attached above right under the question.

Comment: It is 1152000 and using that baud rate for sending data over serial port is working fine. However, i have problem in reading and printing it. In fact, i am not sure if if it's with printing the data received when read and printed. It shows a square symbol and something in it .

Comment: What are you supposed to be receiving? Actual printable data (ASCII, UTF-8...), or binary data? Have you tried dumping as hex (or piping the output into `hexdump`)? Also, you say "sending data at this baud rate is working fine", but how do you know if you can't read responses from the serial port? Are you using the actual same config when writhing? A 1Mbit/s async serial link without any flow control is probably count to fail (lose data) pretty quickly...

Comment: I'm supposed to receive usual binary data. I could send the data (Specifically instructions) at mentioned baud rate without any flow control and data has been loaded into the ROM of my hardware ( A processor logic implemented on FGPA Kit). My hardware is supposed to send me response as Ethernet packets which it's sending and it means data is sent without any problem. What's the command for outputting the read data to printable format?

Comment: If it's binary, it's not really surprising you would be getting weird data if you just print it out. No idea how you print it out as hex in python, hence the suggestion to pipe the output into `hexdump` (probably with the `-C` option so you can see in parallel hex and printable data). Or, if it's indeed Ethernet frames, you may want to pipe it into `tcpdump` or `tshark` if you have Wireshark installed.

Comment: Dear jcaron sir, i would probably send you the screen shot of the response so that it would help me tell you what exactly is happening.  how would i do that?

Comment: Edit your question and add the screenshot in there.

Comment: Dear jcaron sir, the question has been edited and awaits your response.

Comment: Again, it would be better if you piped the response through `hexdump`, but it looks like you're receiving the character with code point 6, aka `ACK`.

Comment: Related: [pythonic way to hex dump files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005505/pythonic-way-to-hex-dump-files)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

---

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    port.write("\r\nSay something:")
    rcv = port.read(10)
    port.write("\r\nYou sent:" + repr(rcv))
```

Comment: Way cool. The power of python ;)

Comment: Gotta love it!!

Comment: Python is not needed indeed. try with a shell and std-commandsl:
$> sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 115200
$> cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump -C